# How do you bitwise shift a Hex String which is of data type string in php?

Tags: php, binary, hex

I have a 2 byte long hex string and need to bitwise shift the 1st one a byte to the left and then add the 2nd byte to it. Both strings come from a 32 character long string. The strings come from a data file I am parsing.

```
$hex="05E000752F0100D0A500503891FB199A"; //example line of data from file

$vcanvbatt=(base_convert(((base_convert(substr($hex,12,2),16,2)<<8)+base_convert(substr($hex,14,2),16,2)),2,10))/100;
```

Comment: `$byte1 = hexdec(substr(...)); $byte2 = hexdec(substr(...)); $result = ($byte1 << 8) + $byte2;` ?

Comment: @DCoder you should post that as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert to binary at all, simply shifting decimal numbers will do. If I understand the math you need correctly, this should work:

```
$byte1 = hexdec(substr($hex, 12, 2));
$byte2 = hexdec(substr($hex, 14, 2));
$result = ($byte1 << 8) + $byte2;
```

Comment: an 8 bit shift wont work on this because the integer isnt 8 bit in php, do you know how long it is?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. An integer in php is most likely to be either 32 or 64 bits depending on the php version, but that is irrelevant - shifting over one byte is the same as `<< 8`, and since the input is just one byte it will not overflow. It might help if you posted some more details about what you're trying to calculate.